# How to modify variables in Azure Pipeline from the same pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Issue updating a value in the Pipeline variable section, but I would like update this value from one task in the pipeline because I need to put a varible value inside of a configuration file in my project and ensure this variable is always updated with each execution.

[image: Variables view]

I was trying update the variable in the pipeline with a Powershell Task using the following command:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;]$version"
```

I can access to this variable using `$(version)`

This update the variable only in the current execution, but not in the variable section. Is it posible to update the variables in the pipeline from a task in the pipeline?